# Anything wrong with bar girl english?

Tags: present-tense

I find teaching a new (young Thai) english conversation learner something like "he no like teacher" vastly easier than "he doesn't like his teacher" because that click of understanding and satisfaction comes much more easily. Of course to grammar purists this kind of bar girl english is scandalous  but the fact is that many bar girls communicate in english much better than native college grads who have studied english for 15 years. The issue is tied up with other questions of class,status, and native teacher inability to converse. Has a school of "simple english" ever been advocated and has any practical consensus reached on the matter?

Comment: It may be a valid step to learning "normal" English, but in normal English-speaking society someone who speaks like that will not generally be regarded as possessing full intelligence and intellect.

Comment: I like the 4 word version better than the 5 word version. Question is, what are the students going to use the language for? "No like" for tourist talk. vs "does not like negotiating with" the international monetary fund.

Comment: I would perhaps aim for native English baby talk (Google "parentese" to get some ideas) rather than pidgin English as a stepping stone, but of course pidgins of various sorts have arisen spontaneously all over the world and throughout history because they do facilitate basic communication more quickly. But whatever you do, please don't teach the term "bar girl English" to your students. As an Asian American woman, the *term* is incredibly loaded and would immediately give me a poor impression of anyone using it.

Comment: @1006a The term *bar girl* sounds *incredibly loaded* to this American white man. I'd bet that pidgin generally takes off on its own faster than "parentese" can be taught. The need to communicate somehow is intense, especially with new crops of tourists arriving every week, many of them speaking nothing but American English.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Yes, I wasn't suggesting teaching parentese, rather perhaps using it to teach regular English (as parents use it to teach babies regular English). As a tool, not an end in itself. The folks on [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com) would probably have better advice about that, though. And thank you for backing up my feeling about the title phrase.

Comment: @1006a  Might work quite well, especially if targeted towards upper class. A cadre of skilled  English speakers could really boost the Thai's international prospects. Course US isolationism might make some other language more useful come mid-century.